# fetching only website details as search engine does

Tags: web, search-engine, web-crawler

I have to fetch website details as search engine does. I need the description of the site,link and some info about them and will store it in my DB. Is there any libraries available for doing this? Please remember I can crawl a whole webpage but I need only the information in the format crawled by search engines.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Take a look at nutch. This SO query might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223536/how-do-we-create-a-simple-search-engine-using-lucene-solr-or-nutch

Answer (score 1):

Which language? APIs and bindings exist for reading webpage content. Do you realize the scale of the task if you wish to create a new 'search engine'? Your question is so generic, there's not a lot of advice that can be given, other than:

Respect robots.txt

Don't hammer the server with requests, you'll soon get your IP blocked by sensible sysadmins.

Comment: I need it in Java and it should just like custom web-search API. I can use JSON/Atom Custom Search API offered by Google but they are limited to 100 search queries per day.